# vim command Termdebug doesn't show source code

Tags: vim-windows

If I open gdb in vim with **Termdebug filename** command it doesn't show source code in bottom window. **cgdb** works proper way with same **filename**.
[image: Termdebug]
[image: cgdb]

Answer (score -1):

I should open source file manually. Termdebug doesn't open source file when I do `Termdebug filename`. So I need to go to Source window and open source file with `:Explore` e.g.